# React eventListener not working as i expect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, console, use-state

so here is my code:

```
import { useState } from 'react'

function App() {
  const [key, setKey] = useState()
  document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
       setKey(e.key)
  })
  return (
    <>
     <div>{key}</div>

     {console.log('hello world')}
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

when i press any key on a keyboard, it should setKey as whatever key i pressed and log 'hello world' in the console.. setting key part is working fine but logging part is what i don't get.. since console.log is outside of eventListener it shouldn't be effected by the eventListener but whenever i press a key, it logs 'hello world' in the console.. i would appreciate if someone help me out on this..

Comment: You shouldn't bind event listeners in a function component body, each time the component renders the event listener is being bound again (creating duplicate listeners). You should use a `useEffect` to bind the event listener and its returned clean up function to unbind the listener. As for the rerenders, whenever you update state you will trigger the component to rerender.

Comment: yes,  your code It's working fine. I just test into my code as well.

Answer (score 1):

In react , whenever the State Updates the Component will rerender..

So Your Console.log was also  rendered while you pressing the Key.